# Can you write in both behavioural and structural verilog in the same module?

Tags: verilog

I understand the difference between structural and behavioural verilog. I am just wondering if you can use both of them within the same module? Or is it bad practice and suggested to stick to one at a time?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: yes, you can. The question is: why? There are not so many places where you need human written structural verilog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the breakthroughs Verilog made in the 1980's was bridging structural and behavioral constructs into a single language. So the direct answer to you question is; yes, it was designed that way. What makes a good practice is a matter of opinion, and that's not a topic for stack exchange.